# Products of sites

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, topos-theory

Does the category of sites (i.e. small categories equipped with a Grothendieck topology) has products? Is there a connection to the product of locales (as discussed in Johnstone's *Stone spaces*, II.2.12) or the product of topological spaces?

Comment: It seems to me that the category of localic groupoids and sites are equivalent (up to some notion of Morita equivalence). This means that one may take two sites, push them over to localic groupoids, take the product, push the result back to sites and that should be the product. I am not 100% sure about this however. See the n-lab site, http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/classifying+topos+of+a+localic+groupoid .

Comment: What morphisms are you using? The 2-category of _sheaf toposes_ has products and pullbacks. The product of two localic toposes is the sheaf topos on the locale product, but the locale product does not always coincide with the topological space product.

Comment: Morphisms of sites (for example see the Wikipedia article).

Comment: Hmmm. That's a difficult category. However it is conceivable that products exist. For example, if we restrict to "discrete" sites with finite limits, i.e. if we look at the opposite of the category of small finitely-complete categories, there are products (which are the same as coproducts). See Lemma B2.3.14 in the _Elephant_.